# show image in different image view when button clicked.

Tags: ios, xcode, imageview

I've been trying to make this code work but can't really get final part together.

I got 2 rows of 6 image views,

Imageview 1 to 6 and 7 to 12.

First I click 6 buttons out of my 26 buttons (A-Z) and they display in the first 6 views with this code:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
if (imageview1.image == nil) {
    [imageview1 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview2.image == nil){
    [imageview2 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview3.image == nil){
    [imageview3 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview4.image == nil){
    [imageview4 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview5.image == nil){
    [imageview5 setImage:image];
} else if (imageview6.image == nil){
    [imageview6 setImage:image];
}
 }

-(IBAction)showA {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"];

[self setImage:img];

}
```

now when I click the button play I want the images to change from view 1 - 6 to 7 - 12.

I hope there is someone who can explain me how to do this, I tried a couple of ways now but Can't really get it working, maybe making variable strings then get the image from that?

hope someone can explain me or has some sample code for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
[imageview7 setImage:imageView1.image];
[imageview8 setImage:imageView2.image];
etc...
[imageview1 setImage:nil];
[imageview2 setImage:nil];
etc...
```

Comment: Hi Just à simple question, when I wanted to do this i did imageview7 = imageview1; this didnt work but my thoughts were THE same, it indicates that I get coding but not this language got Any tips on how to perfect learn these things because They are small obstacles that I shoudnt be struggling with as Much as I am

Comment: What is important to understand in this example is that imageView is a UIImageView object that has a UIImage property called image. You don't want to swap the entire view, just the image it contains. When you set one view equal to another view, you're essentially deleting the one view leaving you with two pointers to the same object.

Comment: I guess fundamentally the issue here is object oriented programming. Perhaps this document could be of assistance to you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you did not set up an image for your UIImageView that it did not alloc a space for the image.

In the other other way CGImage represents the "data of your image". If you did not set up the image but UIImageView alloc the UIImage for you, you are sure that the "data of this image" will be nil (because there is no image).

So you should try that out:

```
if([imageview1.image CGImage]==nil){[imageview1 setImage:image];}
```

Hope that help you

Comment: The above answer helped me but don't realy get what you mean something wrong with THE code? Thanks for responsing! :)